# I am trying to declare an array from my main class with setters

Tags: java

I am trying to declare an array from my main class with setters I don' t know if this is the correct way.In my other class i have all the methods and they work fine but i need to declare the array and it compiles but it doesn't seem like the arrays CC and ccBal are declared.

Here is my code and this is where the problem is. I dont know if i am initializing the array with the setters correctly.

```
public class handleCustomers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Customer [] CC = new Customer[1];
       CC [0] = new Customer();
       CC[0].setCC(new String[]{"1234567894123569"});
       CC[0].setCCBal(new double []{3070.00});
}
```

This is the Customer class

```
public class Customer {

    private String[] CC;
    private double[] ccBal;

    public Customer() {}// default constructor

    public Customer(String [] CreditCards){
        CC = CreditCards;
      }
    public Customer(double [] creditBalance){
        ccBal = creditBalance;
      }
    public String [] getCC(){// Getters
        return CC;
      }

    public double [] getCCBal() {
        return ccBal;
    }
    public void setCC(String [] CreditCards){// Setters
        CC = CreditCards;
    }
    public void setCCBal(double [] creditBalance){
        ccBal = creditBalance;
    }
```

Comment: Show us the `Customer` class

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Please make yourself familiar with the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html). Variable names should start with a lower case letter.

Comment: What happened when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am trying to add value to the arrays CC and ccBal through my ".set" methods. When i compile and run an error comes out saying "Exception in  thread "main" java.lang.nullPointerException". I think this is because neither array CC or ccBal have been initialized. What im asking is if the way im trying to add content to these two arrays is correct because they dont seem to be initialized. Sorry for all the repetition.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you trying to do, I can't ask you in comments because I'm new in StackOverflow. Provide me more information. But that's how you go with this type of problem. And I don't know why you creating array as you just have only one value. Best

public class handleCustomers {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


  Customer bank = new Customer("1234567894123569",3070.00);
  System.out.println(bank.toString());
```

}
}

Customer Class

public class Customer {

```
private String CC;
private double ccBal;

public Customer(String CC, double ccBal) {
this.CC = CC;
this.ccBal = ccBal;
}
public String getCC(){// Getters
    return this.CC;
  }

public double getCCBal() {
    return this.ccBal;
}
public void setCC(String CC){// Setters
    this.CC = CC;
}
public void setCCBal(double creditBalance){
    this.ccBal = ccBal;
}
public String toString() {
  return "CC:" +CC + "balance: " +ccBal;
```

}
}

Comment: Your code does not do the same as the OP's code. The OP allowed multiple credit cards and balances, your code removes that feature. Since the OP is asking about "initializing the array with the setters", that part of his code seems to be important to him.